# How Can I Mock 1 Dependency and Autowire the Other?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, mocking, mockito, autowired

I have 2 dependencies in my controller: a validator and a repository. For this particular test, I'd like to mock the validator, but keep the repository (for now). In previous versions of my code, my controller only had 1 dependency (the repository) and a test setup like so seemed to automatically wire in the correct repository.

```
@Autowired
CreateShortUrlController createShortUrlController;
```

When I introduced the validator dependency, I changed my test setup to the following

```
@Autowired
UrlRepository repository;

@Mock
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();

CreateShortUrlController createShortUrlController = new CreateShortUrlController(repository, urlValidator);
```

Now, when I run my tests, it says my repository is null. Is there anything I can do to retain the "magic" of grabbing the right repository while mocking the other dependency?

Comment: What kind of test is that? @SpringBootTest?

Comment: Yes - @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get familiar with @MockBean, and use it (instead of @Mock) to make spring context aware of your mocked beans.

```
@Autowired
CreateShortUrlController createShortUrlController;

@MockBean
UrlValidator urlValidator;
```

Comment: That works! I noticed my test suite got wayyy slower though.

Comment: SpringBootTest it is much more heavyweight test than WebMvcTest (which is heavier than plain junit test). I wouldn't expect a time penalty larger than a second, though (unless you have a lot of startup time tasks)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@InjectMock` with your `CreateShortUrlController` and use `@Spy` with `UrlRepository` and `@Mock` with `UrlValidator`

```
@InjectMocks
CreateShortUrlController createShortUrlController;

@Spy
UrlRepository repository;

@Mock
UrlValidator urlValidator;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.repository = new UrlRepository();
    this.createShortUrlController = new CreateShortUrlController(repository, urlValidator);
}
```

But you may need think of the dessin of your application and make sure if you need test your UrlRepository here or in infrastructure layer

Comment: Do I have to instantiate the UrlRepostiory here? It was doing it automatically before.

Comment: The UrlRepository is also an interface - I don't have a concrete implementation, yet it works.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to avoid having to explicitly create it, as it seemed to be doing it under the hood before.